# Unable to append string content to html table cell with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I need is append html content to a html table cell with jQuery via append method. This is my code,

```
   $('.add_client').click(function(){
        var table = document.getElementById("client_table");
        var row = table.insertRow(5);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var content = "<strong>Hello</strong>";
        cell1.append( content );
        cell2.append( content );
    });
```

But appended content looks like `<strong>Hello</strong>` instead of just **Hello**. IT will be great if someone can help me on this.

Comment: Please provide complete code

Comment: Can you try `$(cell1).append(content);` problem is cell1 is not a jquery object, so maybe this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using javascript append method not jquery if you want to use jquery append method use it as below `$(cell2).append( content )`

```js
$('.add_client').click(function(){
        var table = document.getElementById("client_table");
        var row = table.insertRow(5);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var content = "<strong>Hello</strong>";
        $(cell1).append( content );
        $(cell2).append( content );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add_client">Add</button>

<table id="client_table">
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>B3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A4</td>
    <td>B4</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A5</td>
    <td>B5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A6</td>
    <td>B5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery all the way?

Comment: @mplungjan i think he got that code from w3school i dont want to disrubt his learning by giving a new approach he wanted to use jquery append that is why i told him that

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery append on a DOM node. You need to wrap the cell in $()

`$(cell1).append(content);`

But since you have jQuery, use it - for example like this

```js
$('.add_client').click(function() {
  let $row = $("<tr/>")
  let content = "<strong>Hello</strong>";
  $row.append($("<td/>").append(content))
  $row.append($("<td/>").append(content))
  $("#client_table > tbody > tr").eq(4).after($row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add_client" type="button">Click</button>
<table id="client_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Row 0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You already wrote the jquery way anyway. Good idea, now if he want jquery all the way he has the code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insertAdjacentHTML` for appending text as html

```js
cell1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', content);
cell2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', content);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is `index`. If index is -1 or equal to the number of rows, the row is appended as the last row. If index is greater than the number of rows, an IndexSizeError exception will result. If index is omitted it defaults to -1. [about insertRow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)

```js
$('.add_client').click(function(){
        var table = document.getElementById("client_table");
        var row = table.insertRow();
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var content = "<strong>Hello</strong>";
        cell1.append( content );
        cell2.append( content );
    });
```

```css
 td {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="add more" class="add_client"/>
<table id="client_table">
 
</table>
```

Comment: You are not solving the problem. You had the IndexSizeError because you had no rows. the problem was using jQuery append on a DOM node